# PHP Post Data overwrites previous text

Tags: php, post

This is the code I am using to post data to txt file on server. I got this from another question on Stackoverflow:

```
file_put_contents('test.txt', file_get_contents('php://input'));
```

The code overwrites all previous text in test.txt everytime. How can I make it insert? I know that if I use fopen, I can make it insert by adding `a+`

```
$file=fopen(date("Y-m-d").".txt","a+")
```

Where should I add a+ in file_put_contents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`file_put_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) supports an optional third parameter: `$flags`. Pass the flag `FILE_APPEND` to `file_put_contents()` to make it append to the file rather than overwriting it:

```
file_put_contents('test.txt', file_get_contents('php://input'), FILE_APPEND);
```

Comment: @Orangepill don't worry. ;) the manual is a large thing. I'm not sure if a person exists who knows about all php functions and their parameters. :)